# adding collapse button to a list

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a collapsible list with a collapse button using the following jquery code, but it's not working.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <button class = 'collapse'>+</button>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

the JQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul').on('click','.collapse', function(e){
       e.stopPropagation();
       $(this).children('li').toggle();
   });
});
```

the toggle button I added did not work at all,
would you please help...
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.collapse').on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(this).hasClass("collapsed")) {
      $(this)
        .removeClass("collapsed")
        .attr("title", "Collapse List")
        .html("-");
    } else {
      $(this)
        .addClass("collapsed")
        .attr("title", "Expand List")
        .html("+");
    }
    var t = $(this).data("target");
    $("." + t).children("li").toggleClass("hide");
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='collapse' data-target="list-1" title="Collapse List">-</button>
<ul class="list-1">
  <li>line 1</li>
  <li>line 2</li>
  <li>line 3</li>
</ul>
```

It is not proper syntax to have a `<button>` element contained within a `<ul>`. This script will check to see the current status of the list based on the button's classes. If it is collapsed, it will expand the list and change the title and value from '+' to '-'. Vice versa it will collapse the list.

If you want to use `.toggle()` you can do so:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.collapse').on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(this).hasClass("collapsed")) {
      $(this)
        .removeClass("collapsed")
        .attr("title", "Collapse List")
        .html("-");
    } else {
      $(this)
        .addClass("collapsed")
        .attr("title", "Expand List")
        .html("+");
    }
    var t = $(this).data("target");
    $("." + t).toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='collapse' data-target="list-1" title="Collapse List">-</button>
<ul class="list-1">
  <li>line 1</li>
  <li>line 2</li>
  <li>line 3</li>
</ul>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide/show the next ul

```js
$(function() {
  $('.collapse').on("click", function(e) {
    let className=$(this).attr('class');
    if(className=='collapse'){
  
      $(this).attr('title',"Expand");
      $(this).attr('class',"expand");
      $(this).next('ul').hide();
      $(this).html('+');
    }
    else{
    $(this).attr('title',"Collapse");
    $(this).attr('class',"collapse");
    $(this).next('ul').show();
    $(this).html('-');
    }
    
    
   });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='collapse' data-target="list-1" title="Collapse List">-</button>
<ul class="list-1">
  <li>line 1</li>
  <li>line 2</li>
  <li>line 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help, I found a simple solution and it worked perfectly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(.toggler).click(function(){
      $(this).parent('ul').children('li').toggle();
     });
 });
```

and for better looks and functionality:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.toggler').click(function(){
    var tick = $(this).text();
    if(tick == '+'){
        $(this).parent('ul').children('li').show();
        $(this).text('-');
       }
    else{
        $(this).parent('ul').children('li').hide();
        $(this).text('+');
        }
    });
});
```